# ClassCastException: Error al comparar tipos de objetos

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente diagrama UML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación adjunto la codificación de la clase `Coordinate`:

```
package edu.uoc.trip.model.utils;


import java.util.Objects;

public class Coordinate  {
    private int row;
    private int column;

    public Coordinate(int row, int column) {
        this.setRow(row);
        this.setColumn(column);
    }

    public int getRow(){
        return this.row;
    }

    private void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        return this.column;
    }

    private void setColumn(int column) {
        this.column = column;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj)  {
        Coordinate coordinate = (Coordinate)obj;
        if ((obj == null) || (obj.getClass()!=this.getClass())) {
            return false;
        } else if ((obj.getClass()==this.getClass()) && (this.getRow() == coordinate.getRow()) && (this.getColumn() == coordinate.getColumn())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(this.row, this.column);
        }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.row + "," + this.column + ")";
    }
}
```

En concreto, me está fallando el método `equals`. La sobreescritura de éste método tiene que devolver `true` cuando dos coordenadas sean la misma, es decir, que sus filas coincidan y sus columnas también. En caso contrario (i.e. sus filas o columnas no coinciden, una coordenada es `null` o se pasa como argumento un objeto que no sea del tipo `Coordinate`), tiene que retornar `false`.

No sé porqué motivo, estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class edu.uoc.trip.model.utils.Coordinate (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; edu.uoc.trip.model.utils.Coordinate is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class edu.uoc.trip.model.utils.Coordinate (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; edu.uoc.trip.model.utils.Coordinate is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

El test que estoy utilizando para evaluar su correcto funcionamiento es el siguiente:

```
void testEquals() {
        assertFalse(c1.equals(c2));
        assertFalse(c2.equals(c1));

        assertFalse(c1.equals(null));
        assertFalse(c2.equals(null));

        assertFalse(c1.equals(new String("Eps!")));

        assertTrue(c1.equals(c1));

        Coordinate c3 = new Coordinate(c1.getRow(),c1.getColumn());
        assertTrue(c1.equals(c3));
        assertTrue(c3.equals(c1));
    }
```

Comment: Es obvio. La primera línea de tu método equals es esta: `Coordinate coordinate = (Coordinate)obj;`. `"Eps!"` es un String, cómo pretendes que almacene ese String en tu objeto coordinate? Lo normal en estos casos es primero poner las condiciones de salida, en este caso, la primera línea debería ser el `if` donde compruebas si es `null` o no es de la clase correspondiente.

Comment: Ya funciona :) Efectivamente, no tenia sentido..haciendo la comprobación primero todo se arregla. Gracias!